# JIRA gadget: how to disable a configuration field

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is there a way to disable a configuration field for a JIRA gadget based on the value of another field?

Example: when the user chooses 'Now' for field Foo, then the Date field is ignored. I'd like to *disable* the Date field. Can this be done? If so, how? I already do the ignoring part. But my only clue for the user that I am ignoring the Date field is my description for Date and Foo. It would be nicer to disable the Date field as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do anything other than use the built-in gadget controls with their standard behaviors, you need to implement your own [gadget configuration code](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Allowing+Configuration+Options+in+your+Gadget) instead of relying on the UserPrefs directly.

This means that, in practice, that you need to omit the ["configuration form"](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/GADGETS/Creating+a+Gadget+JavaScript+Object#CreatingaGadgetJavaScriptObject-ConfigurationForm) from your gadget descriptor, which is this part:

```
config: {
    descriptor: function(){...},
    args: {Function, Array}
},
```

After having removed that, your gadget will then need to build its own UI and decide itself whether or not it still needs to be configured, as well as call gadget.getPref() and gadget.savePref() to get/set your user's gadget configuration options in the parent container.

I should add that this is a fair amount of work. You might be able to do some hacky jQuery to override the standard controls built without doing the above, but this will not likely be portable to different parent containers (or even different versions of JIRA).

Comment: I wonder if someone has a working example that others can gut and tweak. Sounds like it might not be worth the effort if the gadget is for limited internal use. Thank you for confirming that there is no built-in approach for achieving the effect.